# Prolog: DCG Syntax Error

Tags: prolog, syntax-error, dcg

I'm attempting to parse a "function call" for a language that I am creating, but I am getting:

```
:30:0 Syntax error: Operator expected
```

The first line below is where I am getting my error:

```
Fun(FXs) -->   name(F),
                ws,
                [0'(],
                ws,
                args(Xs),
                ws,
                [0')],
                {FXs =.. [F, Xs]}.

 name(N) -->  id(Cs),
             {atom_chars(Cs, N)}.
```

I have exhaustively searched Google for help with errors in DCG parsing, and I have not found anything. An explanation on what I am doing wrong will be helpful, or any resources that would allow me to understand DCG more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's **Fun**: you should write **fun** instead. SWI-Prolog has an extension to allow CamelCase functors, but must be enabled.

Comment: Oh wow, this never occurred to me. Thanks, I really appreciate it.